# Firebase Cannot Create Reference

Tags: swift, firebase

I am a Firebase learning Beginner ,and I think I install all stuff corrected.

But why cannot I creat reference Url

like:

```
let ref = Firebase(url: "somehing.firebaseio.com")
```

[image: here]

Comment: Don't post a picture of text. Instead post the actual text, which makes it a lot easier for people to help you. It will also reduce the number of downvotes your question attracts.

Comment: This is my frist time use Stackflow

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion

Answer (score 4):

It should be

```
 ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
```

The url should be specified in the GoogleService-info.plist that you downloaded and added to your project.

For an example, see the codelab [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-ios-swift/#0)

Comment: But Why the Office website can using like 
let ref  = firebase(url: http://xxxxx.firebaseio.com) 
Cause I saw lots of youtube ,they can coding like that .

Comment: Oh , I think what I saw is older version office website, It update recently Orz 
Thank you